# FireBreath - Getting HTML attrib from a plugin

Tags: html, c++, plugins, firebreath

What is the best way to get HTML attributes from a plugin using FireBreath?

I used the following line for calling my plugin from a web page:

```
<embed src="mydata" type="application/x-myplugin" hidden="true">
```

How can get the value of "src" in plugin ? (e.g. from void MyPlugin::onPluginReady() ?)

I only see things in documentation about how to get params from Javascript objects (http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Interacting+with+Javascript).

Is there a way to get them directly from HTML ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after reading the NPAPI document, I understood these HTML attributes were given to a function (from the API interface) called NPP_New (in parameters argc,argn,argv). Thus, I used my best friend 'grep' (sorry google) and found where this function was implemented in firebreath.

Following the track (npapiPlugin -> ... -> BrowserPlugin -> PluginCorePtr -> PluginCore ), I understood HTML attributes are easily accessible from my plugin class using **this->getParam("src")**.

I suppose we cannot find a simpler solution than... just calling getParam(), so I close this question.